# Data Fusion not allow Struct type from Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm try create a pipeline on Datafusion to read a table from bigquery with `STRUCT` type  but received this error:

```
2021-06-01 19:13:53,818 - WARN  [service-http-executor-1321:i.c.w.s.c.AbstractWranglerHandler@210] - Error processing GET /v3/namespaces/system/apps/dataprep/services/service/methods/contexts/interoper_prd/connections/interoper_bq_prd/bigquery/raw_deep/tables/deep_water_report/read?scope=plugin-browser-source, resulting in a 500 response.
java.lang.RuntimeException: BigQuery type STRUCT is not supported
```

Comment: Can you tell me how did you set up your pipeline ? Also, did you follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/targeting-campaign-pipeline) for general guidelines on how to do it? Currently, BQ Struct type are supported by Data Fusion see [1](https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/CDAP-15256) and [2](https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/CDAP-15665).

Comment: Hi @AlexandreMoraes i added source bigquery in my pipeline and tried connect a bigquery table with struct type, and received the error: 'BigQuery type STRUCT is not supported." i saw the link that you sent, but i dont found the new plugin with this feature

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue. For this reason, I have opened an Issue within [GCP Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) platform, [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190578432).

The product team is already aware of the complaint, as you can see in the case [comments](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190578432#comment2). Please follow the thread for any updates.